# Since when are questions for opinions and resources "no major problems"?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close, disputed-review-audits

I did some close votes reviews today and stumbled over this Review audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/4662763

A quote from the question:

> **My Questions are:**
>
> 1. My idea is correct? Can I do this with my idea?
> 2. Do you know any dll do detcet face gestures for Kinect C# SDK.?
> 3. Do you have any samples of detect gestures?
> 4. Do you have any other ideas how to detect gestures?

The first line, "My Question**s** are"  already is an indication that this question might need some tweaks, since it can be "too broad". But yeah, it doesn't have to mean it is a major problem.

However, question 1 and 4 are asking for opinions and "other ideas", seems like "Primary opinion-based" to me. Question 2 and 3 even make the question worse, since they are asking for "recommend resources".

So all in all, this question seems like it doesn't fit SO to me. However, when voting for closure:

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.** There are no major problems with this question. You should click Leave Open, or make minor corrections via Edit.

Do I miss something? Do I have a wrong idea of on-topic questions for SO? Or does the audit system need some tricks?

Comment: Quite a few questions about issues with the audit system, though I'd agree that it's a problem. If you find bad review audits like this, downvote and/or vote to close the question, then no one else will receive this audit (only applicable to the close queue). The audit system (in the close queue) only checks that there are at least 5 upvotes, 100 views, and no downvotes or close votes (not sure about any answer requirements).

Comment: I close voted that question...

Comment: Question is now closed...

Comment: I'm rather disappointed that this question is closed - I think that if a key part of a question can be answered (and especially if it has answers) then closing it because there are sub-parts which are off topic is unnecessary.  In particular, this question proposes an idea, and it's relatively possible to make technical (vs opinionated) response to that.  Such a response had already been made, and already been accepted.